# Hide Table Row with ASP Control Checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html-table

In my web page, I have a table with a textbox. I want to hide the table row with the textbox If my ASP checkbox is checked. How can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox id="chkbxUS" runat="server" onchange="validate();" />
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="ParentCountryInfo">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=chkbxUS.ClientID%>').checked) {

            document.getElementById("ParentCountryInfo").style.visibility='visible';

        } else {
            document.getElementById("ParentCountryInfo").style.display='block';
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxUS" runat="server" onchange="validate();" />
        </td>
        <td id="ParentCountryInfo">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">Disappear me</asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('<%=chkbxUS.ClientID%>').checked) {
            document.getElementById("ParentCountryInfo").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ParentCountryInfo").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but what if the checkbox is checked from Page load?

Comment: nvm I figured it out `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "validate()", true);`